# retrieve data from 2 joins and retrieve the level for each line with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I have a table with two JOIN : advert,skill, and a level for each line:

[image]

I can get the data with :

```
$listAdvertSkills = $em
      ->getRepository('OCPlatformBundle:AdvertSkill')
      ->findBy(array('advert' => $advert))
    ;
```

How would it be with the "join" method? Something like this?

```
public function getSkillsForThisAdvert($id){
    $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->join('a.advert', 'adv')
            ->where('adv.id', $id) //addSelect here?
            ->join('a.skill', 'sk');
            ->addSelect('sk');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Also, if an array of "category" is inside each advert, if I want to get :
all the categories,
all the adverts from one category,
all the skills required for one advert and the level,

what would be the request?

and in another page, the same but from the skills:
all the skills,
all the adverts with those skills,
all the category from one advert.

It is just to understand the correct way, it is not for any work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the first method will work, but if you want to retrieve data from any of the associated entities, additional queries will be ran.  If you are listing a large number of rows, you may end up dozens of additional queries, so using JOINs and selecting the other entities up front is good practice.

For further explanation - if you join the advert and skill tables in your query builder and do nothing else, your SQL query will join the tables, but it won't select any information from them.  So, if you try to access them later, Doctrine will have to call more SQL queries just to retrieve that information.  That is why the `addSelect` calls are important.  Those tell Doctrine (and SQL) to retrieve all of the information of the associated entities.  If there are 5 additional skills for an advert, for example, your SQL will return 5 rows but Doctrine will hydrate that into an array (or [Doctrine ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html)) of 5 Skill entities that can be accessed from the single Advert object that is returned.

Your QueryBuilder might look something like this:

```
public function getSkillsForThisAdvert($id)
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->addSelect('adv')
        ->addSelect('sk')
        ->join('a.advert', 'adv')
        ->join('a.skill', 'sk');
        ->where('a.id = :identifier')
        ->setParameter(':identifier', $id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

You could also pass the `Advert` object to your function as `$advert` instead and change your query builder call to have `->where('a = :advert')->setParameter('advert', $advert);`

I might also recommend changing the name of the function to `getSkills` since you are already passing the Advert object that you want.

If you don't like using QueryBuilder you can simply use [DQL Queries](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) that look more like SQL (rather than building with QueryBuilder first and then retrieving the query with `getQuery`).  As long as your entities are defined properly with their corresponding associated entities, Doctrine will do most of the heavy lifting for you.  If you want to select one Advert and all of its associated skills, Doctrine will already do the work for you of retrieving one object with corresponding skill objects in an array or ArrayCollection for you, rather than a raw SQL statement that would return multiple rows with duplicates and require you to handle that yourself.

Instead of multiple `addSelect` statements you could also do the following:

```
->select(array('a', 'adv', 'sk'))
```

Also, if you are going to have several WHERE conditions then change your `where` to `addWhere` - in fact it's probably good practice to always use `addWhere` instead.

Comment: OK thank you, about the additional queries, you say the order is important : addSelect then join? Otherwise, join then addSelect create more queries?

Comment: No, when using the QueryBuilder, the order that you call methods like `addSelect` and `join` does not matter at all.  What I meant is that if you don't explicitly select associated objects (with `addSelect`), then if you try to access them later there will have to be additional SQL queries to retrieve those objects.

I will update my answer to give more commentary on what's happening.

Comment: Ok great, I get it. Thank you